# Error running AsyncTask on Textchanged

Tags: android, apache, android-asynctask

I have an EditText in  a fragment where a user will enter the username; as the user enters the name I want to use the onTextChanged event to make a Http Post request to a server and check if that username is available: it will return a status code indicating if the username is available. 
when i run it it give me a errors.  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

```
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // When No Password Entered

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        asycstuffs n = new asycstuffs();
        n.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, 0);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

private class asycstuffs extends AsyncTask<Integer, HomeFeed_Obj, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        BufferedReader in = null;

        String s = Username.getText().toString();

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPut httput = new HttpPut("http://my url");
            String responseBody = "";
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {

                httput.setEntity(new StringEntity(s, "UTF-8"));
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                response = httpclient.execute(httput);
                // /

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Log.d("response ok", "username :/ " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay. Do you have any problems with that?

Comment: error i get Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: in wich line is this error  because i cant see where

Comment: Just a general note on coding style and readability -- class names should be upper case, while members (variables) should be lower case. So 'userName' not 'Username' and 'AsyncStuff' not 'asycstuffs'. Following these conventions will make your code easier to follow for others.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access ui element in doInBackground() method !!

```
 String s= Username.getText().toString();
```

i think you are getting error here , try to pass the string as a parameter , 
also post your logcat values